# How do I creating a jquery selector based on another selector?

Tags: jquery

Okay this question is difficult to phrase.

Let's say I want to create a selector based on another selector:

```
var firstChild = $(textDiv).children(":first")
var firstChildAppend = '.ls-active ' + firstChild;
alert(firstChildAppend);
```

Obviously the output would not contain a usable selector because it would contain a jquery object (what is inside firstChild). Well, I just want to make firstChild text so I can use it to create a new selector.

Comment: What are you going to achieve? Dou you want to add the CSS class `ls-active` to the first child?

Comment: Yeah I want to add ls-active in front of the first child to form a new selector. ls-active is a parent element of firstChild but not the immediate parent. so ls-active actually contains firstChild and its parent (the parent I am using to select it with :first).

Comment: I suggest you post two HTML snippets: one which your code acts upon, and one that is the intended outcome.

Answer (score 1):

You can use find method with your selector to find in its descendant

```
var firstChild = $(textDiv).children(":first")
var firstChildAppend = firstChild.find('.ls-active ');
```

You can also pass the selector in context.

```
var firstChild = $(textDiv).children(":first")
var firstChildAppend = $('.ls-active ', firstChild );
```

I could not understand why you have the final collection returned by selector in alert in statement alert(firstChildAppend), If you want to iterate through returned collection you can use `each()`

```
firstChildAppend.each(function(){
    alert(this.tagName);
});
```

Comment: None of these codes work to create a new selector, unfortunately. I mean if I try to use $(firstChildAppend).hasClass('whatever') for example, it won't work because varfirstChildAppend is an object.

Comment: by the way, .ls-active is a parent element of firstChild. My ultimate goal is to create a selector like $('.ls-active' + firstChild)

Comment: Can you tell what you want to achieve with telling how selector would look like?

Comment: Okay ultimately I want to create a selector like the one used in this expression:$('.ls-active #div_containing_text').toggle(); But #div_containing_text is dynamic. And I'm getting it actually by looping through an object. Thing is, at some point I need to get the first child of another element to create it .. but I don't know how to get just the text of the :first element object name so I can reuse it as a selector.

Comment: but let's just simplify the problem. I have a div with a child. I want to create a selector like this $('ls-active' + FIRSTCHILDOFTHEDIV) That's all I want to do but I can't seem to figure out a way to make FIRSTCHILDOFTHEDIV not an object ... it needs to be plain text so it can be used in a selector.

Comment: You can use object was well but try to use id of first element that you could use later id = $('ls-active :first-child').attr('id');

Comment: If this does not help make a demo on jsfiddle.net and I will try to figure this out.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `.ls-active` is a child element of your first selector, you could use the context selector:

```
var firstChildAppend = $('.ls-active', firstChild);
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way, in case you need the actual selector, would be as follows  :

```
var firstChild = $(textDiv).children(":first")
var firstChildAppend = $(firstChild.selector + ' .ls-active ');
```

This is good for a certain reason of needing the "selector" from the the first criteria if not known, and you need to hold it for a reason. Generally though, Adil has the best solution.`enter code here`